# Remote ESXi builder failing on retrieving VM ip. ESXi 6.0, packer

Tags: linux, vmware, packer, esxi

I'm using a ESXi 6.0 host for testing packer and I've been trying to get the vmware-iso remote ESXi builder to work. With packer 1.0. I get to the point where packer tries to retrieve the guest IP with "esxcli --formatter csv network vm port list -w #######" but errors out saying it cannot find the ip.

Packer log: https://pastebin.com/0TU3HBhQ

jason-file:

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "boot_command": [
        "<enter><wait><f6><esc><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
        "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
        "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
        "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
        "/install/vmlinuz<wait>",
        " auto<wait>",
        " console-setup/ask_detect=false<wait>",
        " console-setup/layoutcode=us<wait>",
        " console-setup/modelcode=pc105<wait>",
        " debconf/frontend=noninteractive<wait>",
        " debian-installer=en_US<wait>",
        " fb=false<wait>",
        " initrd=/install/initrd.gz<wait>",
        " kbd-chooser/method=us<wait>",
        " keyboard-configuration/layout=USA<wait>",
        " keyboard-configuration/variant=USA<wait>",
        " locale=en_US<wait>",
        " netcfg/get_domain=vm<wait>",
        " netcfg/get_hostname=vagrant<wait>",
        " grub-installer/bootdev=/dev/sda<wait>",
        " noapic<wait>",
        " preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg",
        " -- <wait>",
        "<enter><wait>"
      ],
      "communicator": "ssh",
      "disk_size": "{{user `disk_size`}}",
      "guest_os_type": "ubuntu-64",
      "http_directory": ".",
      "http_port_max": "9001",
      "http_port_min": "8000",
      "iso_checksum": "{{user `iso_checksum`}}",
      "iso_checksum_type": "sha256",
      "iso_url": "{{user `iso_url`}}",
      "keep_registered": true,
    "remote_cache_directory": "../packer_cache",
      "remote_datastore": "{{user `host_datastore`}}",
      "remote_host": "{{user `host`}}",
      "remote_password": "{{user `host_password`}}",
      "remote_type": "{{user `host_type`}}",
      "remote_username": "{{user `host_user`}}",
      "shutdown_command": "shutdown",
      "ssh_password": "user",
      "ssh_port": 22,
      "ssh_username": "user",
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
      "type": "vmware-iso",
      "vm_name": "{{user `name`}}",
      "vmx_data": {
        "RemoteDisplay.vnc.webSocket.port": "5900",
        "cpuid.coresPerSocket": "{{user `cores`}}",
        "ethernet0.networkName": "{{user `netname`}}",
        "ethernet0.present": "true",
        "ethernet0.startConnected": "true",
        "ethernet0.virtualDev": "e1000",
        "memsize": "{{user `memsize`}}",
        "numvcpus": "{{user `numvcpus`}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And:

```
{
"wait_90":
"<wait10><wait10><wait10><wait10><wait10><wait10><wait10><wait10><wait10>",
"type": "vmware-iso",
"name": "ubuntu",
"host_type": "esx5",
"host": "***",
"host_datastore": "***/ubuntu",
"host_user": "root",
"host_password": "user",
"guest_root_password": "user",
"disk_size": "7000",
"iso_url": "http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu-releases/16.04.2/ubuntu-16.04.2-server-amd64.iso",
"iso_checksum": "737ae7041212c628de5751d15c3016058b0e833fdc32e7420209b76ca3d0a535",
"cores": "1",
"memsize": "512",
"numvcpus": "1",
"netname": "***",
"guest_hostname": "ubuntu"
}
```

preseed-file: https://pastebin.com/JCCEMs1v

Any ideas?

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

Standard troubleshooting procedure for this:

1. Verify that your preseed correctly configures DHCP.
2. Open up the vSphere/ESXi embedded console for the VM and see the error message or where it gets stuck.